# How to pagination with jQuery and AJAX?

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I want to do the pagination the JSON Result, which is come from the server. I am using HTML5, jQuery and AJAX calls to fetch the data. I am able to get the data from server as like below...

Example: I have received 10 records from server using Ajax call(JSON result) and I want to display 5 records for each page.

```
{"name" : "GPR1"},{"name": "GPR2"},{"name" : "GPR3"},{"name" : "GPR4"},{"name" : "GPR5"},{"name" : "GPR10"},{"name" : "GPR9"},{"name" : "GPR8"},{"name" : "GPR7"},{"name" : "GPR6"}
```

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 3):

You could use some Jquery plugins that paginate your fetched results, simply even if obviuos is to search on Google for "Jquery pagination plugin".
Here on of the results for the search above:
http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/04/best-ajax-jquery-pagination-plugin-tutorial-with-example-demo/.
The custom solution is:

- save JSON data in a global variable (caching in memory)
- putting your own controls for paging (prev. and next buttons)
- bind "click" on paging buttons to fire pagination
- -> pagination is done by using basic javascript "slice" method and then showing data.